# Rooted phone - sending SMS message via command line

Tags: sms, shell, terminal, command-line

I have a rooted Droid (Sholes), with ConnectBot installed.  I can `ssh` into it via `dropbear` copied to `/system/xbin`, and/or also the instance of Debian installed on it via the "Linux Installer" application.  I'm in portable Linux bliss.  But...

I would like to send an SMS message via the shell.  Something like

```
 sendsms 8005551234 "This is a text."
```

Anything like this out there?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to call the messaging intent with

```
am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW "sms:numberhere" -e "sms_body" "hello"
```

Using the intent command as described here:

http://learnandroid.blogspot.com/2008/01/run-android-application-from-command.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967448/send-sms-in-android

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach is to install [Termux](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux&hl=en) and [Termux-api](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux.api&hl=en)

Then ssh in the phone by following this [link](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Remote_Access#SSH)

Now you can send SMS and access many other useful options mainly:

1. Camera
2. Battery Status
3. Clipboard
4. Contacts
5. SMS and Inbox

Full list and syntax can be found [here](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Termux:API)

As it is linux emulator you can use it for many other purposes also.

Comment: Seding sms is no longer permitted by google for termux: https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Termux-sms-send